# OOP - A member function of one class inside a member function of another class

Tags: c++, class, member-functions

A member function of one class within the member function of another class.

Hello. I try that the content of the member function `method()`; of `class B` is printed in the member function `method()`; of `class A`, but I have not succeeded. When trying to compile I get errors.

Do you have any suggestions to fix this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A { 
public:
    void method();
};

class B { 
public:
    int n = 6;
    int x;
    string** plantas;
    string cantidad, m_nombre, m_familia, m_genero, m_luz, m_riego, m_fertilizante;
    static void method();
};

void A::method(){
    cout << "Inicio" << endl;
    B::method();
    cout << "Final" << endl;
}

void B::method(){
    cout << "\n \t ¿Cuántas plantas registrarás?" << endl;
    getline(cin, cantidad);
    x = stoi(cantidad);
    plantas = new string * [n];

    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        plantas[i] = new string[n];
        cout << "\t Nombre: ";
        getline(cin, m_nombre);
        cout << "\t Familia: ";
        getline(cin, m_familia);
        cout << "\t Genéro: ";
        getline(cin, m_genero);
        cout << "\t Ubicación (Luz/Sombra): ";
        getline(cin, m_luz);
        cout << "\t Periodo de riego: ";
        getline(cin, m_riego);
        cout << "\t Periodo de fertilización: ";
        getline(cin, m_fertilizante);
        plantas[i][0] = m_nombre;
        plantas[i][1] = m_familia;
        plantas[i][2] = m_genero;
        plantas[i][3] = m_luz;
        plantas[i][4] = m_riego;
        plantas[i][5] = m_fertilizante;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        delete[] plantas[i];
    }

    delete[] plantas;

    system("pause");
}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.method();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of `B` to call a non-static method on `B`. If you make the method static, then you don't have an instance. There's no middle ground; it's either-or.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods refer to the class as such; non-static methods act on the instance of the class. That's why non-static member functions have an implicit (invisible) first parameter: the instance on which they act.

So with *non-static* methods, you can access non-static members (both fields and functions) and static members (again both), because you have an instance and you can access the class (global) properties.

With *static* methods, you don't have an instance to work on, so you only can use the *static* members (both fields and functions).

In your code, you try to access your non-static member `B::plantas` inside the static member function `B::method()`. This doesn't work. Either you make `B::plantas` static as well, or you make `B::method()` non-static and create an instance of `B` to work with.